# How to parallelize python code on pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, graph, parallel-processing, networkx

I used python to build and visualize ad graph using networkx. Now the problem is that; i don't know if i can apply networkx on spark or not. i want to confirm that networkx is working as parallel processing. The graph should be stored on HDFS, and need to be queried, the result should be visualized. Should i use spark library instead like graphx, despite the graphx i difficult to me and no visualization provided in it so i prefer to use networkx it is more easiest. thanks

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

# directed graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# undirected graph G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'),('C','D'),('G','D')], weight=1,complementray= 1)
G.add_edges_from([('D','A'),('D','E'),('B','D'),('D','E')], weight=2,complementray= 0)
G.add_edges_from([('B','C'),('E','F')], weight=3,complementray= 1)
G.add_edges_from([('C','F')], weight=4,complementray= 0)


#val_map = {'A': 1.0,
#                   'D': 0.5714285714285714,
#                              'H': 0.0}
val_map = {'A': 1.0, 'D': 0.5714285714285714, 'H':0.0}

values = [val_map.get(node, 0.45) for node in G.nodes()]
edge_labels=dict([((u,v),d['weight'])
                 for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])
node_labels=dict([(n)
                 for n in G.nodes(data=True)])
red_edges = [('C','D'),('D','A')]
edge_colors = ['black' if not edge in red_edges else 'red' for edge in G.edges()]

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,node_labels=node_labels)

#arrows=True for directed graph without calling the G = nx.DiGraph()
nx.draw(G,pos, node_color = values, node_size=1500,edge_color=edge_colors,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done some comparison on graph libraries (SNAP vs Igraph vs GraphX) back in 2015, and this is what I can share.

If you want to work in Spark, you're better off learning GraphX to take advantage of the parallel processing. Else just try to find a machine with a bigger RAM and use NetworkX.

We ended up using a combination of igraph + SNAP on a decent spec desktop (28GB RAM) and made some custom heuristics to be able to process some 20M nodes and 300M++ edges. At that point visualizing the network simply didn't make any sense (20M nodes..), and we were more interested in analyzing communities within our subscriber base (telco), so all in all everything was OK. We didn't use GraphX since it was relatively new at that time, and also not much state of the art algos were available.